# Open gauge algebras apart from supergravity theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Does anyone know of a gauge system that is not a model of (super-)gravity where the gauge algebra fails to close off-shell?

Answer (score 3):

One class of models with open gauge algebras are [AKSZ sigma models](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AKSZ+sigma-model), such as, [Poisson sigma models](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poisson+sigma-model), e.g. Ref 1.

References:

1. A.S. Cattaneo & G. Felder, *A path integral approach to the Kontsevich quantization formula,* Commun.Math.Phys. 212 (2000) 591-611, [arXiv:math/9902090](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902090); p. 6.